# Cell Value pickup from different sheet

Tags: excel

I have 5 sheets in a workbook namely `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`.... Maintaining some data in each sheet. In first sheet namely `Consolidation` I need the `B3` Cell value of each sheet to be displayed in each cell

Table in the `Consolidation` sheet will be as below

```
SheetNo|    Name    | value (Value of B3 Cell of respective sheet )
       |            |
1      | Party 1    | Value of Sheet1!B3
2      | Party 2    | Value of Sheet2!B3
3      | Party 3    | Value of Sheet3!B3
4      | Party 4    | Value of Sheet4!B3
:
:
N      | Party N    | Value of Sheetn!B3
:
:
:
Z      | Party Z    | Value of SheetZ!B3
```

I want this to be done most likely through some cell functions only not using VBA Scripting

Answer (score 1):

go to your Consolidation sheet:

```
a1: 1, a2: 2, a3: 3 etc
a2: ="Party "&a1
a3: =INDIRECT("Sheet"&a1&"!b3")
auto fill rest
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something haven't you sort of already answered it with your example?

`=SheetName!Address` will return the value of `Address` on `SheetName`

If you wanted it a little more dynamic so you dont have to manually fill the sheet name, you could do something like this.

`=INDIRECT("Sheet" & Row() & "!$B$3")`

However it will only do numeric sheet names. (unless N and Z are just numbers then theres no problem)

Just looked and saw that you've got the sheet number next in `Column A` so you can substitue `Row()` for `$A$1`

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a cell by name, you can use the `INDIRECT()` function, as in:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$B1&"'!$B$3")
```

Here, `B1` is the cell containing the name of your sheet. The expression inside the parentheses will evaluate to, for example, `'Party 1'!$B$3`. `INDIRECT()` will expand that to the actual value of cell `B3` in sheet `Party 1`.

The extra single-quotes are required to deal with the spaces in your sheet names.

Comment: Excellent & simple solution Thanks a tons

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to StackOverflow. Since you are new here, please make sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), in particular [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) about upvoting and accepting answers.